# All of a sudden, within the last week, my WiFi is constantly dropping throughout the day and I need to reconnect

Tags: wireless, 20.04, xubuntu

I am running Xubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad T420 on an SSD with 32GB of memory. I have changed nothing, just my daily checks for updates, for which there were a few. However, I have not made any configuration changes myself.

The following window keeps popping up:

[image]

Up until this point, I have had no issues with the  WiFi, or anything really, at all.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Comment: I see a lot of "warn" messages. Most of them "connection disconnected (reason 16)" some of them "ifupdown: interfaces file /etc/network/interfaces doesn't exist" and "Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate"

Comment: See `https://aboutcher.co.uk/2012/07/linux-wifi-deauthenticated-reason-codes/` for "error 16".

Comment: `16 - Group Key Handshake timeout. Information element in 4-Way Handshake different from (Re)Association` Well, that was the least helpful thing ever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Some software update I performed in the last day or two has, seemingly, fixed my issue. I'm not sure which update it was, so I guess my advice for anybody facing this is to keep up on your updates.

**Here are my updates from the last two days:**

**2020-12-14:**

- linux-modules-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-headers-5.4.0-58:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-headers-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61)
- linux-image-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61)
- linux-generic:amd64 (5.4.0.56.59, 5.4.0.58.61)
- linux-libc-dev:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62, 5.4.0-58.64)
- linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.4.0-58-generic:amd64 (5.4.0-58.64, automatic)
- linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-20.04:amd64 (5.4.0-56.62, 5.4.0-58.64)

**My Guess Is It Was Something In This Update 2020-12-15:**

- libmagick++-6.q16-8:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- libimage-magick-perl:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- whoopsie:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2)
- libmagickcore-6.q16-6-extra:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- libimage-magick-q16-perl:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 (3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.8-0ubuntu1)
- libmagickwand-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- libwhoopsie0:amd64 (0.2.69ubuntu0.1, 0.2.69ubuntu0.2)
- apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14)
- libinput-bin:amd64 (1.15.5-1ubuntu0.1, 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2)
- imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 (3.36.3.1-0ubuntu1, 3.36.8-0ubuntu1)
- python3-apport:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14)
- libmagickcore-6.q16-6:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- apport-gtk:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14)
- python3-problem-report:amd64 (2.20.11-0ubuntu27.13, 2.20.11-0ubuntu27.14)
- libinput10:amd64 (1.15.5-1ubuntu0.1, 1.15.5-1ubuntu0.2)
- imagemagick-6-common:amd64 (8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.1, 8:6.9.10.23+dfsg-2.1ubuntu11.2)
- libevdev2:amd64 (1.9.0+dfsg-1, 1.9.0+dfsg-1ubuntu0.1)

Good luck.